# Connect a GitLab account with SAML

Tags: ruby, git, gitlab, saml

I am trying to use SAML authentication with GitLab. In the gitlab.rb I specified

```
gitlab_rails['omniauth_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['omniauth_allow_single_sign_on'] = false
gitlab_rails['omniauth_block_auto_created_users'] = false
gitlab_rails['omniauth_providers'] = [
    {
      "name" => "saml",
       args: {
assertion_consumer_service_url: 'https://git.mycompany.com/users/auth/saml/callback',
               idp_cert_fingerprint: 'XX:YY:ZZ',
               idp_sso_target_url: 'https://myidentity.com/SAAS/auth/federation/sso',
               issuer: 'https://git.mycompany.com',
               name_identifier_format: 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress'
             }
    }
  ]
```

Now when I try to login using SAML I get the error

> Signing in using your Saml account without a pre-existing GitLab account is not allowed. Create a GitLab account first, and then connect it to your Saml account.

I have already created a Git User named user1@mycompany.com

How do I fix this error ?

Answer (score 5):

Changing these parameters got it fixed.

```
gitlab_rails['omniauth_allow_single_sign_on'] = true
gitlab_rails['omniauth_block_auto_created_users'] = false
```

Comment: format can be specific:
gitlab_rails['omniauth_allow_single_sign_on'] = ['saml','google','bitbucket','gitlab','etc']

Answer (score 2):

Only `true` in parameter `gitlab_rails['omniauth_allow_single_sign_on']` helps.
The specified list of providers doesn't work for me.
Try to set `true`, not `['saml','google','bitbucket','gitlab','etc']`

*Tested on GitLab 12.3*